# change class value with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
<span class="locked-step"></span>
```

I need to replace class with "showStepsButton"

I want;

```
<span class="showStepsButton"></span>
```

[Site Link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20x%5Csqrt%7B4-x%5E%7B4%7D%7Ddx)

Comment: I don't believe you can use Selenium to actually _change_ the html.

Comment: @AomineDaici There are 7 such elements, which one do you want to change?

Comment: all of them @DebanjanB

Comment: You can done this using `JavascriptExecutor`. This is from Java, but it can give you the idea: `WebElement myElem = ...;` -> `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;` -> `js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'showStepsButton')", myElem);`

Comment: I have no information about Java @KunLun

Comment: Just look for the javascript executor in python and you will get some piece of code like this 
```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('comment-user')[0].click()")
```
This is just an example

Comment: execute_script method will help you to execute the Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get("https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20x%5Csqrt%7B4-x%5E%7B4%7D%7Ddx")
sleep(3)
selects = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='locked-step']")
for select in selects:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'showStepsButton')", select)
```